# Column dropped by DROP SCHEMA ... CASCADE - can I recover the data?

Tags: postgresql, undo

I have a table in Postgresql and a column with hstore type. This requires `hstore` extension. By accident I've removed this addon from Postgresql and the column disappeared. I've reinstalled the addon but the column is still missing. Is it possible to retrieve the missing data?

Comment: How did you "remove this addon from PostgreSQL" exactly? Show the exact series of commands if possible.

Comment: @CraigRinger I've fired `DROP SCHEMA public` (wanted fast cleaning) which apparently caused that. The data I'm talking about was in different schema.

Comment: If the hstore extension was in the `public` schema and was used from other schemas that should've failed with an error indicating that other objects depend on it (and listing them). Did you use `CASCADE`?

Comment: @CraigRinger Ah, yes, I've used `CASCADE`. Sorry, I've forgotten to mention. I've used it since it wouldn't let me delete nonempty tables otherwise. Was stupid idea. I finally understand now that I've actually called `DROP COLUMN` implicitely. I guess that it can't be undone?

Comment: Just a tip for the future to prevent such a thing: that's one of the reasons I install extension into a different schema (`create extension hstore with schema hstore;`). I also always make them owned by the superuser, so a regular user cannot drop them. And finally if I want to cleanup stuff for a single user I use `drop owned by my_user`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, that's a great tip. I will do that from now on, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE`.

This drops all objects that depend on the schema.

`hstore` was installed in the public schema. When it was dropped, so were columns of `hstore` type that depended on it. PostgreSQL emitted a message for each object it dropped, including those columns.

(If you don't use `CASCADE`, Pg tells you what it'll drop if you do use `CASCADE`).

**Stop the database *now*, and make an immediate file-system level backup while the DB is stopped.**

If you haven't updated the table contents since the data is probably still there and can possibly recovered with some surgery to PostgreSQL's system catalogs.

Then you can (maybe) hack the column in `pg_attribute` to point to the new `oid` of the `hstore` type and clear `attisdropped` to get the column back. Maybe. Don't try anything like this on your main copy, you *must* do it on a copy of the backup you made that you start just for this purpose, in case it just makes things worse.

Any rows updated since you dropped the column are probably just gone forever. It's *possible* they could still be on disk and just have xmax set, in which case `pg_dirtyread` can maybe see them. If they got `VACUUM`ed and overwritten then they're just not coming back, though.

Comment: Wow, sounds like some kind of black magic TBH. :) Luckily the data is not sensitive and I can recreate it at any time (it's just quite time consuming). I will try your ideas as well. Thanks!